# invalid choice: 'create_enclave'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using foxy release of ros2 installed from the debian package here: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Linux-Install-Debians.html

I tried to run some simple tests by following the examples here https://github.com/ros2/sros2/blob/master/SROS2_Linux.md

But I end up having an error saying 'create_enclave' is an invalid option. I thought it's a thing that was introduced in foxy so I'm a bit confused. Maybe there's something wrong with my installation but not sure what.

```
$ ros2 security create_enclave
usage: ros2 security [-h] Call `ros2 security <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
ros2 security: error: argument Call `ros2 security <command> -h` for more detailed usage.: invalid choice: 'create_enclave' (choose from 'create_key', 'create_keystore', 'create_permission', 'generate_artifacts', 'generate_policy', 'list_keys')
```

I installed the ros-foxy-ros-base package and apt claims its the latest version:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-foxy-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-foxy-ros-base is already the newest version (0.9.2-1focal.20210226.000028).
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373298/invalid-choice:-%27create_enclave%27/) by [quinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/71409/quinz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In foxy version.
Change command from `create_enclave` into `create_key`.
It work for me.

---

Originally posted by [jufeng wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49417/jufeng-wu/) with karma: 83 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1